# How can I get text value of Option 1, my js always returns the selectedindex value

Tags: javascript, arrays

*Debugger screenshot*:

[image: debugger screenshot]

I am trying to get the selectedIndex Option 1 text value, but my javascript always return the selectedIndex 0 Option 0 value using the code below.

```
x[i] = x.selectedIndex[1];
```

Here is what I've already tried:

```
    var n = "24";
    var x = document.getElementById("TYPE_ID").options;
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (n == "24") {
            x[i] = x.selectedIndex[1];

        }
        else   {
            x[i] = x.selectedIndex[0];

        }

    }
}
```

the if statement still returns the value of Option 0.

Comment: do u want to get the value of option 1 ?

Comment: `x.selectedIndex` gives back a number, what are you trying to do by `[1]` ?

Comment: @AmareshSM yes, currently it returns the value of Option 0.

Comment: @NickParsons How can I get the Option 1 value, as shown in the screenshot for selectedIndex 0?

Comment: then y u r using loop? @user2178940

Comment: @AmareshSM that's for option 0, If n == 24, return option 1, but ig n != 24, then return option 0

Comment: @user2178940 if all you want is the second value you can do something like: `document.getElementById("TYPE_ID").options[1].value;`

Comment: @user2178940 what is `n` ?

Comment: @NickParsons take a look, I just edited the code. It's a conditional statement.

Comment: @user2178940 yes, but where is `n` defined?

Comment: @NickParsons it's before getting the elements by ID.

Comment: In your code for loop is useless could u please specify why u r using that loop @user2178940

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use a for loop in this case. You can use an `if` statement to check if `n` is equal to `"24"`, if it is, then you can output `options.item(1).value`, which will give you the second item in your select dropdown. If it is not `"24"` then you can output `options.item(0).value`.

See example below:

```js
var n = "24";
var options = document.getElementById("TYPE_ID").options;

if(n === "24") {
  console.log(options.item(1).value);
} else {
  console.log(options.item(0).value);
}
```

```html
<select id="TYPE_ID">
  <option>A</option>
  <option>B</option>
  <option>C</option>
</select>
```